# Não consigo relacionar o MongoDB com o Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

Eu to tentando fazer uma página na qual vai ter um formulário escrito `Nome` e `Comentário`, na qual quando a pessoa preencher o nome e o comentário vai aparecer embaixo do formulario. Só que está dando erro.

Aqui embaixo esta meu arquivo EJS e Logo abaixo o arquivo do servidor junto com mongo e as rotas:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>X-Sports</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/quemsomoss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav id="men">
            <ul>
                <li><picture><img class="pho" src="http://i.imgur.com/rjtgdhD.png"></picture></li>
                <li><a href="/Paginajava">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/quemsomos">Quem somos?</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Produtos">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/faleconosco">Fale Conosco</a></li>
                <li><form>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar">
    </form></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="tab">
    <h1>Comentários</h1>
    <form action="/quemsomos" method ='post'>
        Nome:<input type:"text" name="Nome">
        Comentarios:<input type='text' name="Coment"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>

    <table>
        <% for(var i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= resultado[i].Nome %></td>
            <td><%= resultado[i].Comentarios %></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
         
    </table>
    </div>
    </section>


    </body>



    </html>
```

E aqui o do meu servidor ,junto com o mongo

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
require("ejs");
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var app = express();


var Post = mongoose.Schema({
    Nome: "String",
    Comentários: "String",
});

var Coment = mongoose.model('Coment', Post);

var mongo = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Comentarios');

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.static('./app/views'));
app.set('views' , './app/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyparser());


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Paginajava');

    });
app.get('/Paginajava', function(req, res) {
     res.render('Paginajava');

    });

app.get('/quemsomos', function(req, res) {
        res.render('quemsomos');
    });

app.post('/quemsomos', function(req,res){
     var novoPost = new Coment(
        {   Nome: req.body.Nome,
            comentarios:req.body.comentarios,
        }
    );

    novoPost.save();
    resp.render("quemsomos");
    resp.end();
});

app.get("/quemsomos", function(req, resp){
    Coment.find(function(err, resultado){
        resp.render("quemsomos", { resultado: resultado} );
        resp.end();
    });

});

app.get('/produtos', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Produtos');

            
        
    });

app.get('/faleconosco', function(req, res) {
        res.render('faleconosco');
    });

var meuServidor=http.createServer(app);
meuServidor.listen(8080);

console.log("Servidor Rodando" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Existem alguns problemas com o seu código, eu tentei resolver os que geram erros... ;)*

> Você está servindo estaticamente a pasta `/app/views`, que, a princípio, deveria ser usada só pela `engine` (comentei esse trecho):

```
// app.use(express.static('./app/views'));
```

> Logo abaixo, você tem um `app.get` da página `quemsomos`, que está impedindo o segundo `app.get` abaixo de renderizar (também comentei esse trecho):

```
/*
app.get('/quemsomos', function(req, res) {
        res.render('quemsomos');
    });
*/
```

> No seu `app.post`, você está definindo na função `res`, e tentando chamar `resp` - mas tudo bem, remova as duas linhas, e substitua por `res.redirect('/quemsomos');`:

```
app.post('/quemsomos', function(req,res){
     var novoPost = new Coment(
        {
            Nome: req.body.Nome,
            comentarios:req.body.comentarios,
        }
    );
    novoPost.save();
    res.redirect('/quemsomos');
    // res.render("quemsomos"); // removido
    // res.end(); // removido
});
```

> O seu `schema` está usando `Nome` e `Comentários` como chave - e no seu `app.post`, está `comentarios`, sem acento e com letra minúscula. Tire o acento, e deixe os dois com letra maiúscula, para ficar como `Nome`. Além disso, na `view`, você está usando `Coment` e não `comentarios` - eu mudei no `server` para não mexer na `view`, mas sugiro o oposto.

```
var novoPost = new Coment(
    {   
        Nome: req.body.Nome,
        Comentarios: req.body.Coment, // <- é Coment na view
    }
);
```

> Remova o acento aqui:

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({
    Nome: "String",
    Comentarios: "String", // <- estava com acento
});
```

> Segue o código alterado abaixo - mas foi removido todas as páginas que não faziam parte da interação com o DB - é melhor você seguir o passo a passo acima. A idéia é que ele funcione sem ter que mexer na `view` (para teste):

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
require("ejs");
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var app = express();

var Post = mongoose.Schema({
    Nome: "String",
    Comentarios: "String",
});

var Coment = mongoose.model('Coment', Post);
var mongo = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Comentarios');

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.set('views' , './app/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyparser());

app.post('/quemsomos', function(req,res){
     var novoPost = new Coment(
        {   Nome: req.body.Nome,
            Comentarios: req.body.Coment,
        }
    );
    novoPost.save();
    res.redirect('/quemsomos');
});

app.get("/quemsomos", function(req, resp){
    Coment.find(function(err, resultado){
        resp.render("quemsomos", { resultado: resultado} );
        resp.end();
    });
});

var meuServidor=http.createServer(app);
meuServidor.listen(8080);
console.log("Servidor Rodando" );
```

> `Posts` funcionando:

[image: site funcionando com posts]

Comment: Obrigado mano , infelizmente não consegui entregar completo o trabalho , mas estudarei meus erros para prova , muito Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Caio uma parte do código, já que não passou o erro.
Você criou um schema?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var commentSchema = new Schema({
  Nome: { String, , required: true }
  comentarios: { type: String, required: true}
});
```

No link abaixo mostra um exemplo de como fazer.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications
Me diz se funcionou .. abs

Comment: Mudei umas coisas , agora to fazendo de cadastro para apareçer e outra pagina só que ta falando Usuarios is not defined.

Comment: que é a variavel que to usando pra exibir as informações ,

Comment: Caio você tem o projeto no github ? e tiver posso ajudar

Comment: Nem tenho , não sei usar o git hub ainda , to vendo se aprendo kk

Comment: Arthur da uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208106/nodejs-ejs-usuarios-is-not-defined-urgente